# Having Multiple Commands for Calling a Specific Programming Language: To Provide a Delimiter-less Option or Not?

Tags: html, command, maxima, katex

*After re-reading the off/on topic lists, I'm still not certain if this question is best posted to this site, so apologies in advance, if it is not.*

### Overview:

---

I am working on a project that mixes several programming languages and we are trying to determine important considerations for the command used to call one in particular.

For definiteness, I will list the specific languages; however, I think the principles ought to be general, so familiarity with these specific languages is not really essential.

### Specific Context

---

Specifically, we are using: Maxima, KaTeX, Markdown and HTML). While building the prototype, we have used the following (I believe, standard) conventions:

- KaTeX delimited by `$ $` or `$$ $$`;
- HTML delimited by `< > </ >` pairs;
- Markdown works anywhere in the body, except within KaTeX or Maxima environments;

The only non-standard convention we used during this design phase was to call on Maxima using `\comp{<Maxima commands>}`. This command works within all the other environments (which is desired).

Now that we are ready to start using the platform, it has become apparent that this temporary command for calling Maxima is cumbersome for our users. The vast majority of use cases involve simply calling a single variable or function, *e.g.*

> As such, we have $\eval{function-name()}(\eval{variable-name})$

as opposed to actually using Maxima for computation, *e.g.*

> Here, it is clear that $\eval{a} + \eval{b} = \eval{a+b}$

(where `\eval{a+b}` would return the actual sum, as calculated by Maxima).

As such, our users would prefer a delimiter-less command option for invoking a single variable or function, *e.g.* `\@<variable-name-in-Maxima>` and `\@<function-name>(<argument>)` (where `@` is some reserved character not used in the other languages), while also having a delimited alternative for the (much less frequent) cases where they actually want to use Maxima for computation; perhaps something like `\@{a+b}`.

However, **we have a general sense that this is  not a best practice, even though we can't foresee any specific issue**.

### "Research" / Comparisons:

---

Indeed, there is precedence for delimit-less expressions for single arguments like `x^2` (on any calculator) or Knuth's `a \over b` in TeX (which persists in LaTeX with `\frac12` being parsed as `\frac{1}{2}`.

IIRC Knuth's point was that this delimit-less notation was more semantic (and so, in his view, preferable), and because delimiters *can* be added, ambiguity can be avoided, whenever the need arises: *e.g.* `x^{22}`, `{a+b}\over{c+d}` and `\frac{12}{3}`.

### The Question, Proper:

---

**Can anyone point to or explain *actual* shortcomings / risks associated with a dual solution like:**

- `\@<var>`, `\@<function>(<arg>)` and,
- `\@[<extended expression>]`,

(where `@` is a reserved (& escapable) character), **for calling one language amongst others, as opposed to only using a delimited command?**

Any alternative suggestions for how to achieve the ease-of-use and more semantic code enabled by the above solution, while keeping the code unambiguous would be very much welcome and appreciated.

Comment: I guess it makes sense to me to allow for multiple syntaxes, as long as one can unambiguously distinguish them, both from the machine and user points of view. You mention that you are combining Maxima with HTML and TeX -- perhaps you would be interested in a system such as Jupyter, which allows for notebooks which combine text, code, plots, and math, and which can output HTML or other formats. I've worked on a Jupyter kernel (i.e., computational back end) for Maxima, called maxima-jupyter. See: https://github.com/robert-dodier/maxima-jupyter Maybe you can say more about what you're working on.